# Send user/pass through post on open ID

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, openid

I'm new to using open ID and I have downloaded the LightOpenID framework. Currently it has a text link to click and then directs you to the google page to enter your username / password. It then asks you to accept that you trust the site, and redirects back. everything works perfectly, but is there a way to send the username / password for google through a form instead of having to enter it once you get to google? http://web.zealth.net/carlos/test/ this is what I have setup currently. I'd like to have a username / password box that you enter the info into, then sends that to the google page. So it'll automatically login and instead of going to googles login page it will just ask to accept that you trust the site and redirect back to my page to process the variables. Is this possible? If so, how. I don't care if it's jquery / javascript or just a simple post form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the advnatage of using Open ID or oAuth is to stop exactly what you are asking for. i.e Why should I trust you with my username and password? :)

Comment: So you absolutely have to go to google's website to type in your user/pass?

Comment: okay thanks a lot. Tried searching forever for a way lol. At least now I know i'm not crazy. Makes sense though, as I could easily steal your login info before going to the sites (google, yahoo, etc)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make oAuth within a popup, so you dont need to redirect user to auth page and after redirect him back.
[How to authenticate with Google via OAuth 2.0 in a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947038/how-to-authenticate-with-google-via-oauth-2-0-in-a-popup)

Comment: popups are clunky and there isn't many people without popup blockers these days but I may go that route if unnecessary thanks