# Google Drive upload with CORS

Tags: google-drive-api, cors

So, there was a flurry of discussion about the Google Drive API last summer (e.g. a [nicely written answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330992/authorization-of-google-drive-using-javascript/10331393#10331393) by [Nivco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1313169/nivco)), but it has been quite awhile since the last time anybody said something like ["we have let our engineering team know about the issue"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622305/1120220).

So, 8 months later, is there a way to gain any insight into this issue other than to troll old SO questions for updates?

Answer (score 2):

Upload with CORS is now enabled :)

Comment: Thanx guys from our team! Its great!

Comment: @SteveBazyl im having CORS err, files.create works ok but files.update gives me CORS error, why cors error?