# Resumable upload to google drive from JS using XHR

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to do a resumable upload from javascript (client side code)?  I've followed instructions at: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable and I am getting cross domain errors during step 3 (file the upload).  When trying to upload file using xhr (PUT method) as described in example, I get cross domain error in the browser and xhr returns with status 0. The pre-flight seems to work fine. Is CORS supported for google drive upload?

If possible, do you have a link to a working example?

If not possible, when will support be available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, right now it is not, sorry.

The reason as you rightly gathered is that CORS is not yet supported for upload. It will be available soon though, but that doesn't help you right now, so, sorry.

Comment: Already added! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374807/google-drive-upload-with-cors