# Google Drive background login (PHP app)

Tags: php, authentication, google-drive-api

I've been searching for an answer on Google documentations and stackoverflow also, but i did not find answer.
I planned to create application (PHP) which uses google account (ex. admin@domain.com) to store templates of documents. When someone log in to the application using his own credentials (ex. user@domain.com) he can fulfill some form, then PHP application logs into own Google account and store it with data provided by user in new document with template look.

I don't want to redirect user to google and return to application with some token(s). I would like application make some login process in "silent mode" - invisible for user, no redirects.

Simple scheme:

User fulfill form --(sending data to app)--> App logs into own google account (admin@domain.com) --> Get template document --> Fulfill with user's data from form --> save as copy on Google Drive

Can somebody tell me if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/).

You will need to rely on tokens (that's how OAuth works and Google Drive uses OAuth 2.0 for authentication). However, you can tackle the problem of "automatic login" by doing something as follows:

- For a new user, ask them to provide authorization in a popup window ([more details on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947038/how-to-authenticate-with-google-via-oauth-2-0-in-a-popup)). This is essential because they need to approve permissions and such before you can authorize them.
- On successful login, a long-lived token will be returned. Save this token in a database associated with the user.
- For all subsequent logins and requests, you can request new access tokens without having to ask the user for permission.

[This link](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth#authorizing_with_stored_credentials) talks more about requesting new access tokens once the user has already gone through the initial authorization phase.

Additionally, [this link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#scenarios) has several examples of login scenarios (client-side apps, server-side apps, etc.) that will help steer you in the right direction.