# Javascript Closing Popup Window and Redirect parant page to Another Page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple html page in which when I click an image, it opens a new popup that contains a minigame.
When a user finishes the game and closes the popup, it redirects the parent window to a new URL.

Here is my code,

```
    <div class="single-featured img-full">
      <a onclick="openGameWindow();">
         <img src="https://www.htmlgames.com/uploaded/game/thumb500/bubblebilliards500300.webp" width="500px" height="300px" alt=""></a>
     </div>
```

And here is my Script,

```
<script>
        function openGameWindow() {  
            window.open('https://cdn.htmlgames.com/BubbleBilliards/', 
            'popUpWindow','height=400,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
        }
</script>
```

anyone can give a solution on what to add to my script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript open new tab, and wait for it to close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171589/javascript-open-new-tab-and-wait-for-it-to-close)

Comment: "anyone can give solution what to add to my script ?" - anything not working with the current script?

Comment: i tried this ,   <script>
        function openGameWindow() {  
            window.open('https://cdn.htmlgames.com/BubbleBilliards/', 
            'popUpWindow','height=400,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
            window.close('www.google.com');
        }
    </script> but it doesnt work

Comment: Please add all clarification to your quesiton by editing it. "It does not work" does not explain what that code **should** do