# how to retrieve Name property from Google id_token

Tags: java, google-oauth

1. I'm currently implementing Google OpenID to achieve sign in with google on my website. Following the [tutorial given by google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/).
   It emphasizes only the `id_token` is the thing to send to backend-sever. Since I'm using Java as backend and I couldn't find methods like `getName()` on `id_token` in google api library. I can only retrieve email by `getEmail()` though.

   So how can I get user's name at backend?
2. Also, I realized the OpenID is the recommended in docs rather than Oauth2.0 if I only want to validate user's identity. I tried to implement Oauth2.0 too, but stuck on its working flow.

   Here is what I get so far.

   - button clicked ---> send a http get to certain api
   - that api got invoked and run [scribeJava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/blob/master/scribejava-apis/src/test/java/com/github/scribejava/apis/examples/Google20Example.java) code
   - after I get the `Authorization url`, how do I open it as a popup window for user's confirmation?
   - and after confirmation, how to send the authentication code back to sever?

I know the blue map, but quite confused about the specific implementation.

Any help?

Answer (score -1):

1. It's better to use OAuth2 in my opinion: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetbasicprofile Then you can fetch the basic user profile and then the username you wanted.

> fetch_basic_profile Fetch users' basic profile information when they
>   sign in. Adds 'profile' and 'email' to the requested scopes. True if
>   unspecified.

2. I believe you can use google api (gapi) for Oauth in Javascript. Here is the documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication
   So here you can find a sample code to that:
   [How to authenticate with Google via OAuth 2.0 in a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947038/how-to-authenticate-with-google-via-oauth-2-0-in-a-popup)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: hes asking about openId not oauth2.

Comment: is Oauth in JavaScript a replacement for JAVA/PHP api library? Seems it does all the stuff and take advantage of front-end work